# In azure devOps, how to duplicate dashboard in a project

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a dashboard in my project and I insert widgets to show team progresses. Currently, there are 2 teams in the dashboard and they each have 8 widgets. I want to split them so that each team have their own personal dashboard. Since I don't want to actually make it from scratch I want to duplicate it and just delete the other team's widget in each of their new personal dashboard. Is there any documentation of how to do this or is it currently not possible?

EDIT 1

Here is
[My Current Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmlXx.png)

I want to duplicate the dashboard or copy the widget content if it is possible, so that blue team and red team have their own dashboard without me having to make it again from scratch (duplicate then just delete the other team's widget would save much time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to duplicate the dashboard or copy the widget content if it is possible

The requirement can be understood as using a dashboard template so that we don't have to waste time on dropping widgets to a new created dashboard one by one.

This is actually a user voice you can follow at [Copy dashboards between team projects or have dashboard templates](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365536/copy-dashobaords-between-team-projects-or-have-das.html).

Its state is "On Roadmap" which means this function is not available at current time but might be in future updates.

Which available nowadays is that you can [copy configured widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/add-widget-to-dashboard?view=azure-devops#copy-a-widget) from one dashboard to another.

Or if it's urgent, i recommend you can try the [python script](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/880221/view.html) @Matthew Pollock provided in the [uservoice thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/880120/view.html).

Hope this could help.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, please see my edited question above

Comment: My apology for misunderstanding the requirement, i have edited my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with PowerShell you can use [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS) to copy a dashboard. The Copy-APDashboard command support cross collection and cross project copying.

The following will copy a dashboard into the same project as the source.

```
Copy-APDashboard -Name 'My Current Dashboard' -Session 'mySourceSession'
```

The following will copy a dashboard into a different project in the same collection.

```
Copy-APDashboard -Name 'My Current Dashboard' -Session 'mySourceSession' -TargetProject 'Other Project Name'
```

The following will copy a dashboard into a different collection if the sessions are configured as such.

```
Copy-APDashboard -Name 'My Current Dashboard' -Session 'mySourceSession' -TargetSession 'myTargetSession'
```

See [AzurePipelines Session Management](https://github.com/Dejulia489/AzurePipelinesPS#creating-a-session) for more details on how to create a session and save it for use in later PowerShell sessions

### **Note**:

Copy-APDashboard does not copy the underlying queries, only the dashboard widgets and scope.